# Assign Roles to multiple users and System Identity using Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-rbac

I have requirement to assign Azure Roles to multiple users on subscription scope and Reader role to Managed Identity-Storage Account.

1.Assign Azure **RBAC** roles to multiple users

2.Assign system assigned managed identity to existing Virtual Machine, Role **Reader**

Here is the script.

```
$vm-(Get-Azum-ResourceGroupName <Resourcegrpupname> -Name <VMName>),identity.principalid 

New-AzRoleAssignment -Objectid <Objectid> -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/<Id>/resourceGroups/VResourcregroup Name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/StoragrAccounts/<storageaccoumt>

New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <ID> -RoleDefinationName <RBACRule> -Scope '/Subscription/<I'D>`
`
```

Script is working,butneed to assign same roles to multiple users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assign Azure **RBAC** roles to multiple users":

To assign roles to multiple users at the same time, simply form a *group* by adding *users* who need the **"reader"** role assignments.

***Created a group under*** `AzureAD -> Groups`:

[image]

```
new-azroleassignment -objectID <ObjectId of group> -Roledefinitionname "Reader"  -scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG/..." #Give scope of the resource as per the requirements.
```

***Output:***

[image]

> 1. Assign system assigned managed identity to existing Virtual Machine:

Previously, System assigned identity status is *Off*:

[image]

*If not for any particular roles, You can directly update VM configurations/identities by using below commands*:

```
$vminfo = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName xxxxxxRG -Name xxxxVM
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName xxxxxxRG -VM $vminfo -IdentityType SystemAssigned
```

[image]

*System assigned identity status is* ***"ON"*** *now:*

[image]

> 2. Assign system assigned managed identity to existing Virtual Machine, Role **Reader**:

Using PowerShell, you may configure identities for the appropriate app roles under App services. To work with VMs, use `AzCLI` command
[`az vm identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/identity?view=azure-cli-latest) to assign the system-assigned identity as shown here:

```bash
az vm identity assign -g xxxxResourceGroup -n xxxxVirtualMachineName --role Reader --scope /subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG
```

***Assigned***:

[image]

***Updated:***

- Assigning 'reader' role from [VM managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-cli#use-azure-rbac-to-assign-a-managed-identity-access-to-another-resource) to access a storage account:

```bash
SID=$(az resource list -n newVM --query [*].identity.principalId --out tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $SID --role 'Reader' --scope /subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount>
```

[image]

- Assigning Azure **RBAC** roles with scope as storage account:

```
new-azroleassignment -objectID <ObjectId of group> -Roledefinitionname "Reader"  -scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/xxxxRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount>
```

[image]